# Problems with imported files

Tags: objective-c, xcode, import

I'm having some trouble working with a small library that uses another library. Even when I include both libraries in the same Xcode project, I keep getting errors that have to with imports.

I've tried linking the files together by drag and drop, including them as frameworks, and and copying and pasting them into the project folder, but I still keep getting errors.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: set the header search paths.

Comment: I tried doing that, but I still get the same problem

Comment: how you are setting it?

Comment: i looked around, and set it under "search paths" under "build settings", using the directory of header files.. isn't that the way?

Comment: set directory as one directory back of header files.

Comment: yeah.. it's still not working. :(

Comment: After some fiddling around, this does indeed seem to solve the problem with the header files. Thanks!

Comment: Give answer to your own question.